# Different address make same signature for one message

Tags: wallets, addresses, etherscan, signature

Is it possible two different wallets (address) make the same signature for one message?

I have one message: '010025819ecc6e01000000000000000000000000000000000000b735b643314b4e512020204c271c0eff02003b0f000000' and two different addresses: '0x222682ef86452de181cfdbb173261e31ea9c7f3e' and '0x93a12ef77d452f49b789077b142ec87407ac15f8'.
Both addresses produce the same signature '0xf48423551081e974fb0fb6cd13342dd54bf5ad552076da4b3738d6ce9bcb6d951400af5ada5f487897aac29393f1a3e4fc51bb8239dec2b397e3c7075f1116931b'.
I verified this in https://etherscan.io/verifySig and both pass the verification.
Why this is possible?

Comment: What did you use to sign the message?

Comment: Code developed by me with code pieces and functions from other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum uses ECDSA public key recovery algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Public_Key_Recovery to verify signatures.

The recovery algorithm allows multiple possible solutions.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the point. I appreciate that. But regardless of the algorithm used, it should yield the same result. Or not ???